# how to apply list methods on a slices in python

Tags: python, list, substring

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
x = a[1:]
x.insert(0,5)
```

this works
but i want to combine all these statements into a single one to use it in a list comprehension
what is want is

```
x = a[1:].insert(0,5)
```

i can see what is wrong with this but but i cant find a correct method,

the exact code is somewhat similar to this

```
spacelist = [ alist[1:].extend(alist[:2].insert(0,1)) for i in range(0,len(alist))]
```

i can see the mimstake here, like by using those methods on the slices we are attemptming to change original array.
any alternatives?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do here. You have a `list` called `a` and you want a list called `x` that is the same but starting with a `5` instead of a `1`. There are no strings or substrings in your question, just lists and slices (and an overly-complicated list comprehension).

Comment: i changed substring to slice, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about trying something like this :

`x = [5,] + a[1:]`

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions for their own sake are a mistake. Stop trying to make your code clever and cool and make sure people can read and comprehend what's going on in your code. If you want, put a "TODO" comment near it and update it later when you figure out how to do what you want. I suggest this in the hope that the TODO comment is discovered and deleted when you get more experience and decide that list comprehensions for their own sake are a mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just use:

```
x = [5] + a[1:]
```

I think your list comprehension should be

```
spacelist = [alist[1:] + [1] + alist[:2] for i in range(len(alist))]
```

But I'm not quite sure what it's supposed to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
x = (lambda x: x.insert(0,5) or x)(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `list.insert()` returns nothing. You can try to add new methods to `UserList` but `UserList` is implemented in Python much slower than `list`, so this might not be an option.